# ArrayList throwing null pointer expection

Tags: java, arraylist

I keep getting a null point exception when try to add data to an ArrayList. I've looked online and all the answers say make sure you initialize the ArrayList, which I did, but I'm still getting a null pointer exception. Any ideas?

```
package resources;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class CoursesSupportBean
{

    private String url;
    private String DataSourceName;
    String error;
    private List<Object> allData = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public String course_name;
    public int courseId;
    Object obj=new Object();

    public CoursesSupportBean() {
        url="";
        DataSourceName="";
        error="";
        allData = null;
        course_name="";
        courseId=0;
        obj=null;
    }


    public void setObj(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setDataSourceName(String DataSourceName){
        this.DataSourceName=DataSourceName;
    }

    public List getDb_Data()
    {
        String framework = "embedded";
        String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
        String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
        //HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        //String url = (String)session.getAttribute("url");
        //String DataSourceName = (String)session.getAttribute("DataSourceName");
        //res.setContentType("text/html"); 
        //PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        Context ctx = null;
        java.sql.Connection conn = null;
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,url);
        ArrayList statements = new ArrayList(); // list of Statements, PreparedStatements
        PreparedStatement psInsert = null;
        PreparedStatement psUpdate = null;
        Statement s = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        int i=0;
        try 
        {
            ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
            try {
                ctx.createSubcontext(DataSourceName);
            }
            catch (NameAlreadyBoundException e) {
            // Subcontext already exists.
            // Note that WebLogic's Context implementation does not throw this
            // exception if the name is already bound to an identical object.
            }
            String dbName = "JHU";
            try {
                javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup(DataSourceName);
                conn = ds.getConnection();
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                s = conn.createStatement();
                statements.add(s);
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("----- SQLException -----");
                System.out.println("  SQL State:  " + e.getSQLState());
                System.out.println("  Error Code: " + e.getErrorCode());
                System.out.println("  Message:    " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Naming Exception");
        }
        try 
        {   
            rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM COURSES");
            if (rs == null)
            {
                System.out.println("No rows in ResultSet");
            }
            while (rs.next())
            {
                DataFields d=new DataFields(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));                    
                System.out.println("Course data: "+ rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));
                this.allData.add(i,d);
                i++;
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("----- SQLException -----");
            System.out.println("  SQL State:  " + e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("  Error Code: " + e.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("  Message:    " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
                rs = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("----- SQLException -----");
            System.out.println("  SQL State:  " + e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("  Error Code: " + e.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("  Message:    " + e.getMessage());
        }

        // Statements and PreparedStatements
        int c=0;
        while (!statements.isEmpty()) {
            // PreparedStatement extend Statement
            Statement st = (Statement)statements.remove(c);
            try {
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                    st = null;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("----- SQLException -----");
                System.out.println("  SQL State:  " + e.getSQLState());
                System.out.println("  Error Code: " + e.getErrorCode());
                System.out.println("  Message:    " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        //Connection
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("----- SQLException -----");
            System.out.println("  SQL State:  " + e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("  Error Code: " + e.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("  Message:    " + e.getMessage());
        }
       return this.allData;
    }
    public int getCourseId()
    {
        this.courseId=((DataFields)obj).courseId;
        return this.courseId;
    }
    public String getCourse_Name() {
        this.course_name=((DataFields)obj).course_name;
        return this.course_name;
    }

    public class DataFields
    {
        public String course_name;
        public int courseId;

        public DataFields(int courseId, String  course_name)
        {
            this.courseId=courseId;
            this.course_name=course_name;
        }
    }

}
```

**Log Cat Error**

> java.lang.NullPointerException at resources.CoursesSupportBean.getDb_Data(CoursesSupportBean.java:109)

Comment: Put in the full exception including stack trace and say which line in your code corresponds to what line in the stack trace.

Comment: Should have been a little more specific. The this.alldata.add(i,d); is the line that is throwing the exception. It's line 109. I've tried with and with the "this." descriptor as well.

Comment: Please *edit* the question rather than posting 5 stacktrace comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ArrayList is initialized by the definition as a field, here:

```
private List<Object> allData = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

But you seem to be setting the very same allData to null in your constructor here:

```
public CoursesSupportBean() {
    url="";
    DataSourceName="";
    error="";
    allData = null;
    course_name="";
    courseId=0;
    obj=null;
}
```

So you're getting a null pointer exception because you're setting the ArrayList reference allData that already has been initialized to null again (no longer points to the created ArrayList)

Just remove this line:

```
allData = null;
```

Normally, you initialize all members in the constructor, but initialization of collections is usually left in the field definition, unless it is an expensive operation and thus is left to a late as point as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the `allData` `ArrayList` to `null` in the constructor. Remove this line:

```
allData = null;
```

from there. Typically, if you want to initialize variables in the constructor, just declare them in the class outside of the constructor and initialize them only in the constructor. In other words, replace the above `allData = null;` line with:

```
allData = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

replacing this line outside of the constructor:

```
private List<Object> allData = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

with this:

```
private List<Object> allData;
```